# How to convert flax saved checkpoints to model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jax, flax

https://github.com/google-research/scenic/tree/main/scenic/projects/mbt
I am trying to use the pretrained model present in the git, which is basically a Flax Checkpoint. I want to convert it back to the model. How can I do that?

[image: Saved Checkpoints]